# Save server module

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

```
  let JoinedServer = ServerDoc.findOne({id: guild.id})
  if (!JoinedServer) {
  let server = new ServerDoc({ id: guild.id, ServerName: guild.name });

  await server.save();
  console.log(server);
  }
  let JoinedEmbed = new MessageEmbed({
    title: "Joined Guild",
    description: `Joined ${guild.name} \n Mebers: ${guild.memberCount}`,
    image: guild.iconURL(),
    color: "GREEN",
  });
  client.channels.cache
    .get("962440588530159636")
    .send({ embeds: [JoinedEmbed] });
});
```

when it joins a server it sends the message Embed But Not Save The Server in Data Base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerDoc.findOne(...)` returns a promise and thus has to be awaited before checking for existence.

```js
let JoinedServer = await ServerDoc.findOne({id: guild.id})
if (!JoinedServer) {
  // ...
}
```